# Siddhi Event Tables are not properly working with Apache storm

Tags: wso2, apache-storm, wso2-cep

I have tried to use event tables in my execution plan and try to join table with input stream in  WSO2 CEP v4.1.0 in distributed mode with Apache Storm.

Here is my Siddhi query.

```
@Plan:name('ExecutionPlan')

@Import('InputStream:1.0.0')
define stream InputStream (id string, param1 int, param2 double, param3 string, param4 string, param5 string, param6 string, param7 string);

@Export('outputStream:1.0.0')
define stream OutputStream (id string, param3 string);

@From(eventtable = 'rdbms' , datasource.name = 'MYSQL' , table.name = 'cep') 
define table cepTable (id string, param1 int, param2 double, param3 string, param4 string, param5 string, param6 string, param7 string);

@name('query1') 
@dist(parallel='2', execGroup='Filtering')
partition with ( id of InputStream )
begin
  from InputStream join cepTable 
  on cepTable.id == InputStream.id 
  select InputStream.id as id, InputStream.param3 as param3  
  insert into OutputStream;
end;
```

But it provide following exceptions

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-13 14:19:11,847] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.admin.EventProcessorAdminService} -  Error while initialising the connection, null 
org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.exception.ExecutionPlanConfigurationException: Error while initialising the connection, null
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.EventProcessorDeployer.processDeploy(EventProcessorDeployer.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.EventProcessorDeployer.executeManualDeployment(EventProcessorDeployer.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.save(EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.java:95)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.CarbonEventProcessorService.editInactiveExecutionPlan(CarbonEventProcessorService.java:181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.admin.EventProcessorAdminService.editInactiveExecutionPlan(EventProcessorAdminService.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.stub.EventProcessorAdminServiceStub.editInactiveExecutionPlan(EventProcessorAdminServiceStub.java:2473)
    at org.apache.jsp.eventprocessor.edit_005fexecution_005fplan_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(edit_005fexecution_005fplan_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ExecutionPlanRuntimeException: Error while initialising the connection, null
    at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.rdbms.DBHandler.<init>(DBHandler.java:79)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.RDBMSEventTable.init(RDBMSEventTable.java:119)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.helper.DefinitionParserHelper.addEventTable(DefinitionParserHelper.java:99)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.ExecutionPlanRuntimeBuilder.defineTable(ExecutionPlanRuntimeBuilder.java:74)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.defineTableDefinitions(ExecutionPlanParser.java:194)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.parse(ExecutionPlanParser.java:140)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:53)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createExecutionPlanRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.common.storm.component.SiddhiBolt.init(SiddhiBolt.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.common.storm.component.SiddhiBolt.<init>(SiddhiBolt.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.util.StormTopologyConstructor.constructTopologyBuilder(StormTopologyConstructor.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.StormTopologyManager.submitTopology(StormTopologyManager.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.CarbonEventProcessorService.addExecutionPlan(CarbonEventProcessorService.java:314)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.EventProcessorDeployer.processDeploy(EventProcessorDeployer.java:124)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.rdbms.DBHandler.<init>(DBHandler.java:73)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 95 more
```

What is the reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the execution plan is deployed on WSO2CEP server, having following annotations would be enough,

```
@From(eventtable = 'rdbms' , datasource.name = 'MYSQL' , table.name = 'cep')
```

given that we have defined a datasource called `'MYSQL'` among the datasource configurations in the WSO2CEP server.

However, when the exceution plan is deployed on Storm, datasource configuration has to be specified inline (because datasource configurations defined in the WSO2CEP server are not available within Storm).
This can be done as below:

```
@From(eventtable = 'rdbms' , jdbc.url='', username='', password='', driver.name='' , table.name = 'cep')
```

Fill in the annotation elements appropriately.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check whether you have configured MySQL connection. For configuring MySQL connection check below link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Setting+up+MySQL

Check server is reachable, schema is available on the server with the table needed(cep). Is the schema name "MYSQL" is correct. Please check.

2) Check the storm clustering configuration in event-processor.xml file. For more information on configuration check below link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+CEP+4.1.0#ClusteringCEP4.1.0-DistributedmodedeploymentDistributedCEP

Comment: You have provided links to set up MySQL fordatasources to manage registry or user management data. It is irrelevant. My data-source is working fine. Apache storm also working fine. Simple siddhi queried that wso2 provided are working fine. but rdbms table join is not working with storm. That is my question?